# Prove that perpendicular bisector of orthic $\triangle$ bisect side opposite to it

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC $ $D,E,F$ are feet of perpendiculars from vertex $A,B,C$ respectively. How do I prove that perpendicular bisector of $FE$ bisect $BC$ when extended.[image]

Comment: I think I got the prove,$F,B,C,E$ are con cyclic points.Also $S$ is center becoz $\angle BEC=90^o$.Hence perpendicular from center of circle bisect the chord ($FE$).Please tell me my apporach is correct or not.And I need yours answer also.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, $BC$ is the diameter of the circumscribed circle of $\Delta BCE$ and of $\Delta BCF$. So, since $FE$ is the chord of this circle, that perpendicular bisector of $FE$ include the center.